# Get lineEdit Input data

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, qt4

I'm new to qt4, and I'm trying to get the input text data. But I'm not getting.

Would anyone could help me? I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Example of what I'm doing:

adduser.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "adduser.h"

myQt_user::myQt_user(QDialog *parent)
{
    setupUi(this); // this sets up GUI
    connect(pushButton_adduser, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(add_user()));
}

void myQt_user::add_user()
{
    users = lineEdit_user->text();
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Data"),tr("Get user:" +users ));

}
```

adduser.h

```
#ifndef ADDUSER_H
#define ADDUSER_H

#include "ui_dialog_useradd.h"


class myQt_user: public QDialog, private Ui::windows_add
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
        myQt_user(QDialog *parent = 0);
        QLineEdit *lineEdit_user;
        QString users;

public slots:
        void add_user();
};

#endif
```

Erro:

```
adduser.cpp:-1: In member function 'void myQt_user::add_user()':

adduser.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to 'myQt_user::tr(const QString)'

adduser.h:9: candidates are: static QString myQt_user::tr(const char*, const char*)

adduser.h:9: note: static QString myQt_user::tr(const char*, const char*, int)
```

Comment: Please describe the actual problems you have. Without knowing what's in your UI file, it's impossible to fix your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Qt way to do it is the following:

```
QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Data"), tr("Get user:" +users ));
```

should be

```
QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Data"), tr("Get user: %1").arg(users));
```

Comment: Excellent point!  Localizes the prompt without touching the data.

Comment: Exactly, the tr mechanism is very powerful and the QtLinguist ignores the arguments inside a tr formatted string. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq03-swedish-chef.html

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you're passing a `QString` to a function that takes `const char*`:

```
QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Data"),tr("Get user:" +users ));
```

Either don't call tr, or pass it a `char *`:

```
QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Data"),"Get user:" +users); // removed tr
```

or

```
QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Data"),tr(qPrintable("Get user:" +users)));
// get a char* from the QString with the qPrintable macro.
```

(Since you probably don't want to localize user input, I'd go with the first option.)